# Scraping dynamic amazon page with scrolling

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape products on Amazon's Best Seller 100 for a particular category. For example -

https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Home-Kitchen/zgbs/home-garden/ref=zg_bs_nav_0

The 100 products are divided into two pages with 50 products on each page.

Earlier, the page was static and all 50 products use to appear on the page. However, now the page is dynamic and I need to scroll down to see all 50 products on the page.

I was using scrapy to scrape the page earlier. Would really appreciate if you could help me out with this. Thanks!

Adding my code below -

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class BsrNewSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bsr_new'
    allowed_domains = ['www.amazon.in']
    #start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/kitchen/ref=zg_bs_nav_0']

script = '''
    function main(splash, args)
        splash.private_mode_enabled = false
        url = args.url
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(0.5))
        return splash:html()
    end
'''

def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/kitchen/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'
    yield SplashRequest(url, callback = self.parse, endpoint = "execute", args = {
        'lua_source': self.script
    })

def parse(self, response):
    for rev in response.xpath("//div[@id='gridItemRoot']"):   
        yield {
            'Segment': "Home", #Enter name of the segment here
            #'Sub-segment':segment,
            'ASIN' : rev.xpath(".//div/div[@class='zg-grid-general-faceout']/div/a[@class='a-link-normal']/@href").re('\S*/dp/(\S+)_\S+')[0][:10],
            'Rank' : rev.xpath(".//span[@class='zg-bdg-text']/text()").get(),
            'Name' : rev.xpath("normalize-space(.//a[@class='a-link-normal']/span/div/text())").get(),
            'No. of Ratings' : rev.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'a-size-small')]/text()").get(),
            'Rating' : rev.xpath(".//span[@class='a-icon-alt']/text()").get(),
            'Price' : rev.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-base a-color-price']//text()").get()
            }      
        
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[text()='Next page']/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield SplashRequest(url, callback = self.parse, endpoint = "execute", args = {
                'lua_source': self.script
            })
```

Regards
Sreejan

Comment: Share code to show what you’ve tried so far

Comment: I have added my code. Please ignore the indentation error, some issue while pasting it. I am getting 30 results from page 1 and 8 results from page 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate approach that does not need Splash.

All 50 products' ASIN is hidden on the first page itself. You can extract these ASIN and build all those 50 product URLs.

```
import scrapy
import json

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings ={
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS':''# Important
    }
    name = 'amazon'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Home-Kitchen/zgbs/home-garden/ref=zg_bs_pg_1?_encoding=UTF8&pg=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        raw_data = response.css('[data-client-recs-list]::attr(data-client-recs-list)').get()
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        for item in data:
            url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{}'.format(item['id'])
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)
    def parse_item(self, response,):
        ...
```

Comment: Hi Upendra, 

I am able to run this logic using the scrapy shell, instead of the css path I am using
raw_data = response.xpath("//div/@data-client-recs-list").get()
Then I follow the rest of your code and I get the 50 ASINs on the page.

However, when I run this code using "scrapy crawl amazon" I am getting and error because raw_data is 'NoneType' . Could you please help me with this? Thanks !

Comment: use `inspect_response(response,self)` in `parse` method. This will open a scrapy shell. Examine the response to adjust the XPath.
Also makes sure that you are using the correct headers (`DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS` in `settings.py`).

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the patience Upendra! Really appreciate the help!

1) Default Headers - I am using the line you shared in code and also changed the Headers in the settings.py file. 
2) Used the inspector_response method similar to the one I saw in your Youtube videos. When I run the xpath in the shell it does not work and raw_data is a none object.
3) But surprisingly, if I directly run the shell, then the xpath works perfectly fine !

Could you please share your settings.py Default Request Header lines ? I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: 1. Run`pip install scraper-helper`
2.  ```import scraper_helper 
....
custom_settings ={
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': scraper_helper.headers()
    }
```

Comment: The idea is to send all the usual headers the browser sends. Above is just a shortcut I use. You can take all the headers by examining network traffic from your browser.
Also, [see this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html).

Comment: Thanks Upendra! It finally started working for me. Got to learn a lot!